# after modified the config files in /etc/presto/conf, how to restart presto-server

Tags: amazon-emr, presto

In aws emr, after modified the config file in /etc/presto/conf, how can we restart presto-server? Just on master node or on all nodes?

Answer (score 3):

On EMR you can restart Presto with

```
sudo stop presto
sudo start presto
```

You should do this on every node where you modified the config file. You should also update the config file on every node, as appropriate.

Comment: so, if I want to change /etc/presto/conf/config.properties, I have to change the file on every node, not just on the master one, right? and then issuing the above stop & start command?

Comment: Right. You can use eg `presto-admin` or some other tool to automate this. BTW I recommended that you take a look at Starburst (our) Presto AWS integration (https://www.starburstdata.com/presto-aws-cloud/). It offers lower TCO over EMR (https://www.starburstdata.com/technical-blog/starburst-presto-on-aws-18x-faster-than-emr/).